# Trouble installing boost when running the bootstrap.bat file through the command prompt (log included here)

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013, bootstrapper

I am having trouble while installing boost. My OS is windows 7 and I am using VS 2013 express. I have downloaded boost and unzipped it to the directory c:\boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0. I then opened the VS cmd prompt Start -> All Programs -> Visual Studio 2013 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Developer Command Prompt for VS2013. I then entered the following into the cmd prompt, "cd C:\boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0", then, bootstrap (and bootstrap.bat). This is what the command prompt displays.

---

```
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>cd c:\boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0

c:\Boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0>bootstrap
Building Boost.Build engine

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.

c:\Boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0>
```

---

I have tried re-installing VS and the .NET (4.5.1) framework and trying the above again. Below is the bootstrap log. If anyone can shed some light on this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
###
### Using 'vc11' toolset.
###
C:\Boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 
C:\Boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap 
C:\Boost\1.57.0\VC\12.0\tools\build\src\engine>cl /nologo /RTC1 /Zi /MTd /Fobootstrap/ /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG -wd4996 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c 
command.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
compile.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
constants.c
debug.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
execcmd.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
execnt.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
filent.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
frames.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
function.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
glob.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
hash.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
hdrmacro.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
headers.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
jam.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
jambase.c
jamgram.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
lists.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
make.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
make1.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
object.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
Generating Code...
Compiling...
option.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
output.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
parse.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
pathnt.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
pathsys.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
regexp.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
rules.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
scan.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
search.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
subst.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
timestamp.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
variable.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
modules.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
strings.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
filesys.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
builtins.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
md5.c
md5.c(55) : fatal error C1034: string.h: no include path set
class.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
cwd.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
w32_getreg.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34) : fatal error C1034: ctype.h: no include path set
Generating Code...
Compiling...
native.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
set.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
path.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
regex.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\modules\../mem.h(67) : fatal error C1034: stdlib.h: no include path set
property-set.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
sequence.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\strings.h(11) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
order.c
c:\boost\1.57.0\vc\12.0\tools\build\src\engine\modules\../mem.h(67) : fatal error C1034: stdlib.h: no include path set
Generating Code...
```

---

Comment: Looks like your VS setup is borked: "ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder" Either that or you picked the wrong architecture of the VS Tools Command Prompt

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify your toolset for building boost.

```
$bootstrap vc12
$b2
```

Currently supported toolsets are: borland, como, gcc, gcc-nocygwin, intel-win32, metrowerks, mingw, msvc, vc7, vc8, vc9, vc10, vc11 (from this [article](http://andres.jaimes.net/718/how-to-install-the-c-boost-libraries-on-windows/)) and vc12 (I tested it myself.)

Answer (score 1):

The following process worked for me:

1. Add environment variables: `C:\Windows\System32`;
2. Go to the directory `C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts` and open the VS2013 x64 Compatible tool command prompt method. Then change directory to the root path of the unzip boost using the `cd` command. For example, my path is d:\boost_1_64_0
3. Run the command：`bootstrap.bat vc12`
4. Successful production of bjam.exe. Open bjam.exe auto-compile and wait for about ten minutes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHoz.png)
The point is step 2, and you can't do it directly.